# Powershell to connect to a remote linux ssh server and executing a command line

Tags: windows, powershell, ssh, haproxy

I have to connect from a Windows 10 / Windows Server 2016 machine to a Linux machine (CentOS) to execute a command to disable a server in haproxy. On a local Linux machine the command is `sudo echo "disable server http/test1" | socat tcp:127.0.0.1:9191 stdio` and it works. But I have to create a script / command line to let a Windows machine do the magic. I´ve tried [powercat](https://github.com/besimorhino/powercat) but it will not work. So I decide to use ssh client on the Windows machine. The command line is
 `ssh -l haproxy-user -i private.ppk 10.0.0.20 "sudo echo "disable server http/test1" | socat tcp:127.0.0.1:9191 stdio"` but I didn´t get the option to enter the passphrase for my identy file. Or is there another option to execute the command line?

Comment: If you want to use public key authentication without user interaction the private key must not have a passphrase (or it must've been loaded into an SSH agent beforehand).

Comment: Do you have any hints how I could do this? How should the command line looks like?

Comment: The commandline would look the same. You need to remove the passphrase from the private key (e.g. with PuTTYgen).